# Lost in Pokémon Y!

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I’m playing *PokémonY*, but it's been long time since I last played it, and I don’t know where I’m supposed to go! Could I get some help?

**Information:**

- The latest Holo-Caster message is ”A declaration!”.
- I only have 7 gym badges.
- I can’t get into Route  18 or  Snowbelle Town.

Comment: If you could add a screenshot or some graphical information it would be easier to help you...

Comment: Screenshot/Graphical information on what exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Likely this means you need to progress with the Team Flare story arc. Go to Lysandre Cafe in Lumiose City. Inside you can enter Team Flare's base. Will avoid saying more since you may not want more spoilers.

[Here's a brief video on catching a cab to get there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BuKCozb4zBA), since you may have forgotten how to get there if it's been a long time since you last played.

Comment: thank u for the help sooooo much it was realy helpfull and i can now progress!

Comment: @SonHuku thanks for the praise. Could you please accept the answer by hitting the check mark underneath the voting buttons if it answered your question?